# How to get all required credentials for Payment Pro and Express Checkout method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal

I am trying to set up Paypal Pro and Express Checkout method with my sandbox credentials.

below required values for Payment method configure

1. partner
2. user
3. vendor
4. password

Can anyone please tell me that from the Paypal account, from where can I get those details?

Here is the screenshot for a better understanding
[image]